# when I want to logout in drf api browsable it shows HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in DRF and now I have an Error in logout in DRF API browsable

when I want to logout in API browsable it shows me Error 405 (method not Allowed)

this is my setting.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

this is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

please tell what can I do to fix this Error

as I said I'm new in DRF so I just Wrote this codes nothing else

I think this Error its because BasicAuthentication

Comment: You log out with a POST request.

Comment: I used post man to send a POST request but it gives me CSRFToken Error
I give my csrf token in headers to postman but it gives me CSRFToken Error

Comment: You can not really pass that to Postman, or at least not just some token you got some time ago, that is the entire point of a CSRF token: to prevent tools like postman to make post requests, and that is why the DRF normally does not do CSRF validation.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem How do you logout with a POST request in DRF ? Do you have to overwrite the default logout process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on Django version you are using. If you are using Version 5, try downgrading to 4.2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue with django 5. downgrading django fixed this.

To downgrade Django to a specific version, you can use the pip install command with the version number. Here are the steps:

1. First, check your current Django version. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

   ```
   pip freeze
   ```

This command lists all the packages installed in your environment, including Django.

2. To downgrade Django to a specific version, use the pip install command followed by ‘==’ and the version number. For example, if you want to downgrade to Django version 3.1.14, you would use:

   ```
   pip install django==3.1.14
   ```

This command will uninstall the current version of Django and install version 3.1.14.

Please replace ‘3.1.14’ with the version number you want to downgrade to.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a problem with django 5 which hasn't been resolved yet. I downgraded back to 4.2.5 and the logout function immediately started working again without changing any other settings. For now, I think this is the best solution until Django can iron out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to downgrade your Django version as proposed by the other answers, you can create a super user, connect to admin page and then logout.

Of course it's only a temporary workaround while DRF fixes the real POST logout issue.